# Maintain scroll position with jQuery Mobile slide transition

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I'm currently developing a mobile websiteon which I use jQuery Mobile. When switching pages I use the slide transition. Because these pages are quite long scrolling is needed.

When scrolled down and clicking on a link there is a visible jump when the page is scrolled to the top before sliding in the new page. As the two pages sit side-by-side when transitioning scrolling to the top is needed at some point.

One thing I've tried is this:
I can offset the new page from the top so that it begins at the level the page is scrolled to and reset the offset back to 0 when the animation is complete, but then the page will remain scrolled down. If I use window.scrollTo or jQuery's scrollTop() there is a noticeable flicker most noticeable with the fixed header.

Is there any other thing I can do which keeps the old page scrolled but the new page unscrolled?

I've tested this in an iPod touch 3rd gen, iPhone 4 and iPhone 4s, and surprisingly the device which has given me the least amount of flicker so far has been the iPod touch.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add this CSS

```
div[data-role='page'] { bottom: 0; -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; }
```

(from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15255719/jquery-mobile-prevent-scroll-to-top-before-page-transition))

Answer (score 0):

I am answering this question because it is the original one posted about this topic, and states clearly that the issue here is a noticeable flicker by using `window.scrollTo()`, `jQuery's scrollTop()` or the controversial `$.mobile.silentScroll()` from the JQM library (timeout + scroll).

I have had recently to address exactly the same issue, and that is what I came up:
the great JQM team has done a great job in the past to optimize and speed-up transitions also for low-end mobile devices.

In short, this critical point has been solved by JQM in some way by trying to pair the `pages` to a certain value inside the `§.mobile.silentScroll()` function. I had to remove this function to build my own:

```
$(document).on("mobileinit", function () {
  // other settings...
  $.mobile.SerialTransition.prototype.scrollPage = $.noop;
  $.mobile.ConcurrentTransition.prototype.scrollPage = $.noop;
});
```

As I have two kind of pages, the first one where I need to remember the scroll position (list page), and a second one (card page) where I need to start always from the top, I will store this information inside a custom `data-attribute`.

Here is for instance this setting for the three pages in my example below:

```
<div id="page-one" data-role="page" data-transition-scroll="keep-position">
<div id="page-two" data-role="page" data-transition-scroll="top-position">
<div id="page-three" data-role="page" data-transition-scroll="keep-position">
```

As pointed out in the question, I have had also to offset the `page` from the top, and this is the whole code:

```
var scrollHandler = {
  setScrollData: function (prevPage, toPage) { 
    if(typeof toPage == "object" && typeof prevPage == "object") {
      $(prevPage).data("scroll-top", $(window).scrollTop());
    }
  },
  resetContent: function (toPage) {
    var scrollMode = $(toPage).data("transition-scroll");
    if(scrollMode === "top-position") {
      var content = $(toPage).find(".ui-content")[0];
      var contentStyle = $(content).attr("style"); /* Force reflow */
        $(content).css({"top": "0px"});
    }
  },
  freezeContent: function (prevPage) {
    var scrollTop = $(prevPage).data("scroll-top"),
        content = $(prevPage).find(".ui-content")[0],
        fixedHeader = $(prevPage).find(".ui-header-fixed")[0],
        headerBottom = $(fixedHeader).outerHeight() - fixedHeader.offsetTop;
    $(content).css({"top": -scrollTop + "px"});
    window.scrollTo(0,0);
  },
  unFreezeContent: function (toPage) {
    var scrollTop = $(toPage).data("scroll-top"),
        scrollMode = $(toPage).data("transition-scroll"),
        content = $(toPage).find(".ui-content")[0],
        contentStyle = $(content).attr("style"); /* Force reflow */
    $(content).removeAttr("style");
    window.scrollTo(0, scrollMode ==="top-position" ? 0 : scrollTop);
  }
};
```

The JQM `pageevents` used here are are the following:

```
$(document).on("pagecontainerbeforehide", function(e, ui) { 
  scrollHandler.freezeContent(ui.prevPage);
});

$(document).on("pagecontainerbeforechange", function(e, ui) { 
  scrollHandler.setScrollData(ui.prevPage, ui.toPage);
});

$(document).on("pagecontainerbeforeshow", function(e, ui) { 
  scrollHandler.resetContent(ui.toPage);
});

$(document).on("pagecontainershow", function(e, ui) { 
  scrollHandler.unFreezeContent(ui.toPage);
});
```

Lastly, there is also a little bit of CSS:

```
/* large desktop screen */
.ui-header,
.ui-content,
.ui-footer {
  max-width: 870px;
  margin: auto;
}
/* needed for the scrollhandler */
.ui-content {
  position: relative; 
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

**Additional note**

For *external pages* and for pages which aren't *dom-cached*, there would be the need for a custom page history because:

1. in my example the scroll value is stored inside the page itself and
2. the current standard JQM page history implementation it would not be enough for this purpose

---

**Here is an example:**

The `slide` transition was slowed down on purpose to examine the result:

[image: transition animation]

Answer (score -1):

just put return false;
at the end of the javascript function that is called.

```
     function yourFunctionBeingCalled(){
       /*your code*/
       return false;
     }
```

you can also use preventDefault(); or event.stopPropagation(); functions

reffer:
[event.preventDefault() vs. return false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false)

Hope it helped.