# jQuery mobile anchor jump to the top of page

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have issue with jquery mobile anchor. When I click on _blank link with some anchor I redirect to new page in new tab and navigate to anchor link. But when page is fully loaded  page jump to the top of page

```html
<a href="http://www.my_site.com/some_page#reviews" rel="external" data-ajax="false">Click me!</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have any JS code in your jQuery Mobile `Page Load` events.

Check if you have any

> Move to Top of Page code in your `$( document ).ready()` function.

Also, check this resource link for events that triggers when page is fully loaded

> http://api.jquerymobile.com/category/events/

check this link out too, if it helps :

[jQuery Mobile prevent scroll-to-top before page transition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15255719/jquery-mobile-prevent-scroll-to-top-before-page-transition)

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Can I catch event when jqm scroll to top?

Comment: @Стас Пишевский 

You can check out this [THREAD](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17441065/how-to-detect-scroll-position-of-page-using-jquery). 

Check if `scroll == 0`, which means you are on the top of the page.